# What happens if a client does not install your self-signed ssl certificate?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certbot

I have a Django project that is to be run on a LAN network, hence I use a self-signed certificate for HTTPS. If a client does not install the certificate, it shows "Not Secure". Does that mean that HTTPS is not used, or that it is used, just that the "Not Secure" message is shown as a precaution?

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean that HTTPS is not used, or that it is used, just that the "Not Secure" message is shown as a precaution?

It means that HTTPS is used but that the client cannot verify that it talks to the expected server. This means encryption will still be done - but this might be encryption with some attacker instead of the intended server.